# Направление SVG linearGradient

Tags: javascript, svg

У меня есть простой линейный градиент внутри круга.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
  <linearGradient id="ct-svg-gradient" gradientTransform="rotate(65)">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red" />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellow" />
  </linearGradient>

  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="url(#ct-svg-gradient)"/>
</svg>
```

Как вы можете видеть, я пытаюсь повернуть градиент на 65 градусов.
По крайней мере  [документы](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform#Types_of_transform_definition) заявляют, что это возможно.  Я попытался установить этот поворот на большее число, и это не дало ожидаемого результата.

Я понимаю, что проблема  заключается в том, что `linearGradient` не может трансформировать `transform origin` в центр.

Я предполагаю, что мне придется использовать атрибуты `x1, y1, x2, y2` для линейного градиента, без градиентной трансформации. Если это так, то какой самый простой способ получить эти четыре значения, если у меня есть только угол, на который я должен вращать градиент?

Я заинтересован в реализации такой функции, мой вход динамичен.

```
function convert(angle_in_degrees) { // or radians, I'll take care of conversion

  // the algorithm I'm interested in

  return {
    x1: ...,
    y1: ...,
    x2: ...,
    y2: ...,
  };
}
```

Буду благодарен за любой ответ.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
  <linearGradient id="ct-svg-gradient" gradientTransform="rotate(150)">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red" />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellow" />
  </linearGradient>
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="url(#ct-svg-gradient)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/36749960/7394871

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это не так просто. чтобы ваш градиент мог заполнить объект от края к краю, вам нужно будет также передать его и принять во внимание его `bounding box`.

Если вам нужно только применять градиент к  кругам, тогда было бы проще применить ориентированный по оси градиент и повернуть круг.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
  <linearGradient id="ct-svg-gradient">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red" />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellow" />
  </linearGradient>
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="url(#ct-svg-gradient)" transform="rotate(150,100,100)"/>
</svg>
```

**Update**

Вот простая функция JS, которая делает то, что вы хотите. Это не всегда даст лучшие результаты, но это должно быть легко понятно.

```js
function setGradientAngle(elementId, gradientId, angle)
{
  // Конвертирование угла в радианы
  angle = angle * Math.PI / 180;
  // Получить ограничительную рамку элемента (bounding box) 

  var bbox = document.getElementById(elementId).getBBox();
  // Вычисление центра вращения
  var cx = bbox.x + bbox.width/2;
  var cy = bbox.y + bbox.height/2;
   //Минимальный радиус, который нам нужен, чтобы гарантировать, что градиент растягивает всю ширину
   //Этот расчет может быть более умным. Мы просто делаем худший случай здесь для простоты.
  var radius = Math.sqrt(bbox.width*bbox.width+bbox.height*bbox.height)/2;
   //Вычисляем вектор от центра к градиентным координатам
  var rx = Math.cos(angle) * radius;
  var ry = Math.sin(angle) * radius;
  // Обновление градиентных координат
  var grad = document.getElementById(gradientId);
  grad.setAttribute("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse");
  grad.setAttribute("x1", cx - rx);
  grad.setAttribute("y1", cy + ry);
  grad.setAttribute("x2", cx + rx);
  grad.setAttribute("y2", cy - ry);
}

setGradientAngle("mypath", "ct-svg-gradient", 150);
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
  <linearGradient id="ct-svg-gradient">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red" />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellow" />
  </linearGradient>
  <path id="mypath" fill="url(#ct-svg-gradient)" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" d="M116.48,288.71a582.68,582.68,0,0,0-69.84-40.32q-36.32-17.74-33.52-58.06a582.72,582.72,0,0,0,0-80.65Q10.32,69.35,46.64,51.61a582.68,582.68,0,0,0,69.84-40.32q33.52-22.58,67,0a582.67,582.67,0,0,0,69.84,40.32q36.32,17.74,33.52,58.06a582.65,582.65,0,0,0,0,80.65q2.79,40.32-33.52,58.06a582.67,582.67,0,0,0-69.84,40.32Q150,311.29,116.48,288.71Z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Непреодолимое желание)), в последних твоих ответах прикрутить функционал, вращения по часовой, против, чтобы мышкой, пальцем можно было, как будто не хватает))

Answer (score 1):

если SVG используется в контексте HTML+CSS,
то самое простое, это применить вращение через CSS,
где можно задать центр вращения, а не смещение относительно координат.
примерно так:

```css
img{transform-box:fill-box;transform-origin:center;transform:rotate(65deg)}
```

```html
<img src="./circle.svg" />
```